# Retrieving data from Nested HashMap

Tags: android, hashmap

This is my HashMap declaration:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>>> myMap;
```

Now I have created 2 arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> FirstAL = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> SecondAL = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In onCreate() I have added items to arraylist and to HashMap

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FirstAL.add("a");
    FirstAL.add("b");
    FirstAL.add("c");

    SecondAL.add("1");
    SecondAL.add("2");
    SecondAL.add("3");

    myMap.put("myKey", new HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>());
    myMap.get("myKey").put(FirstAL, SecondAL);

    // now while retriving I'm getting null instead of Arraylist
    ArrayList<String> resultAL = myMap.get("myKey").get("a");

}
```

Thnx in Advance. Please help me to figure where did I went wrong?

Comment: Use `FirstAL` as key to retrieve value as `myMap.get("myKey").get(FirstAL);`

Comment: I'm trying ur suggestion

Comment: Voila its working. It gives SecondAL as result but how to determine from which key of FirstAL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use:

```
myMap.get("myKey").put(FirstAL, SecondAL);
```

where `FirstAL` is `ArrayList` but then you try to retrieve the stored value using a `String` key:

```
myMap.get("myKey").get("a");
```

Use `FirstAL` instead of `"a"` or declare `myMap` as `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>` depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah replacing "a" with FirstAL does the job but can u plz tell me for which FirstAL key the result is returned? How to specify the Key "a" to retrive result ArrayList?

Comment: @kevz you can use [`List.indexOf`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method for that, check the example

Comment: Imagine that I'm having different values for a, b and c keys. Then how to retrive values related to a, b and c resp? Didn't got wt were u trying to say earlier List.indexOf

Comment: @kevz Then you should definitely use `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>` for myMap

Comment: allright gotcha. I'd designed it wrong. Thnx for ur guidance.